# Present a view modally in NSDocument's window

Tags: macos, modal-dialog, swift, nswindow, nsdocument

I have an `NSDocument` subclass that has its own xib file. Also I have an `NSViewController` subclass with its own xib file too, and I want to present its view modally, like this one.
[image]

Problem is, it always shows it as a separate floating window without title bar.

The view I'm trying to present is contained in a window in that xib file. And yes, it's Mac OS X 10.10. Here's the code.

```
    @IBAction func didPressEditF(sender: AnyObject) {
        let controller = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        let window = self.windowControllers[0].window as NSWindow
        window.beginSheet(controller.view.window, completionHandler: didEndPresentingF)
    }
```

It's OK if you help me using Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. I figured it out.

At first. We need a property of our `ViewController` class so it won't get released after showing.

```
var controller: ViewController?
```

Then we need a method that will return a window of the current document. Somehow `self.windowControllers[0].window as NSWindow` doesn't work.

```
    func window() -> NSWindow {
        let windowControllers = self.windowControllers
        let controller = windowControllers[0] as NSWindowController
        let window = controller.window
        return window
    }
```

And finally, the code that opens up the sheet window will look like this:

```
    @IBAction func didPressEditF(sender: AnyObject) {
        controller = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.window().beginSheet(controller!.view.window, completionHandler: didEndPresentingF)
    }
```

Apple HAS to do something with their outdated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of digging through the document's window controllers, you could call windowForSheet, a method on NSDocument. E.g. self.windowForSheet.